# Exporting a node module with a component library in Angular?

Tags: angular, jwt, node-modules, angular-library, angular2-jwt

I made a component library using the Angular CLI and I have have a separate test application that imports this library.

The component library builds nicely, but I am having trouble running "ng serve" in the test application because one of the components in the library uses an npm package I specifically installed in the library: 'jwt-decode".

For instance one component in the library has the line:

```
import * as jwt_ from 'jwt-decode';
```

And the library's package.json has the lines

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0"
 }
```

While the component library builds correctly, when I ng-serve the application that imports this library, I get the error:

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jwt-decode' in '.../dist/myLibrary/fesm2015'.**

Basically, how do I export a package(that I npm installed in the library), with the component library itself. Do I need to add anything to the library's public-api.ts file?

Comment: You have to install the dependencies into the application that uses the library. So you have to run `npm install jwt-decode` in the app.

Comment: Theres no way around this? I'm trying to abstract this, since only the component needs it from the component library and not the separate application.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Angular. This is how npm works. You have a peer dependency and the app might be using the same library but a slightly different version. So the app decides which library gets installed and what version.